# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes" when execute with Darknet53 network

Tags: python

I’m writing source code to execute with Darknet53 network. If input of Darknet53 is keras tensor then it worked but  I add more code as below then it has error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

(cause: Keras can't create model if you used a tensorflow operation without wrapping it into a layer). 
I convert tensorflow tensor to keras tensor by Lambda but it still not work.
Please help me!

```
def identity_layer(tensor):
    return tensor

def darknet_body(input_darknet):
   # input_darknet is Keras tensor
    # detail is tensorFlow tensor because  function training.inference write on Tensorflow<br/>
    detail = training.inference(input_darknet)  
    print(detail.shape) # (?, 408, 408, 3)
    print(K.is_keras_tensor(detail)) # False
    # Convert detail to Keras tensor
    x1 = Lambda(identity_layer)(detail)  
    print(K.is_keras_tensor(x1)) # True

    # Darknet53
    x = DarknetConv2D_BN_Leaky(32, (3, 3))(x1)
    x = resblock_body(x, 64, 1)
    x = resblock_body(x, 128, 2)
    x = resblock_body(x, 256, 8)
    x = resblock_body(x, 512, 8)
    x = resblock_body(x, 1024, 4)

    # create model
    model = Model(input_darknet, x) # Error at here

    # Retun
    return x
```